# Can two laravel app use thesame database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-replication

I have two laravel projects with setup as follows:

App1 - Web application portal
NB: Currently on a remote server
Allow students to submit applications and check the status of their applications online. Tables include (users, students, applications, documents, comments, faqs, answers)

App2 - Corp App
NB: On our local server
Allow to evaluate applications submitted via App1, view reports, manage selected applications, generate letters, 
etc. Tables include (users, students, applications, documents, interns, attestations, supervisors, messages, etc). App2 do not share login information with App1. It mainly contains login info of corp employees while App1 only contain login info of students and site administrator. Tables common between the two dbs are students, applications, documents and via master-master replication we are able to get all applications submitted to App1 on the remote server and on App2 we can update the status of the applications which is sync back to App1 DB. Now we want both applications and db to be on thesame server and so for replication to work , that would mean installing two instances of mysql with each database on a separate instance. Would it be better to just include all the tables of the website - App1 (comments, faqs, answers, etc) on App2 DB and make both applications now use one database?

Comment: In short yes, they can use the same database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the easiest solution with one database. 
here is a link on how to use laravel and lumen together:
http://blog.enge.me/post/building-api-your-laravel-application-lumen

not excactly the same, but i think the principles can be reused for your project.
BTW, doesn't laravel 5.2 support user roles out-of-the-box?

When i think about it, you can actually do it with 2 user tables and 2 user models, each with its own login controller/middleware. Then you point the students to domain.com/student/login and the employees to domain.com/employee/login.